# mongoose Parent refrence: virtual populate doesn't show any results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a parent schema (tours) and a child schema (reviews), Each tour has many user reviews. my problem is no matter what I do the reviews won't be populated when I query a specific tour as I want it to do

Reviews Schema has a fields called tour and writer:

```
tour: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Tour",
      required: true,
    },
writer: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: "User",
  required: true,
},
```

Tours Schema is going to populate (virtual populate) all reviews related to it:

```
// Virtual Populate :
tourSchema.virtual("reviews", {
  ref:"Review",
  // specifing the names of the fields (the foreign field and local field) in order to cennect the data sets :
  localField: "_id", // the field where we store the data of foreign key we have gotten .
  foreignField: "tour", // the field where the tour's id is being stored .
  count: true
});
```

also, I've included the schema options for all of my models:

```
{
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }, // means I need the virual to be part of the output .
    toObject: { virtuals: true }, // mean I want it to be outputed as an obj .
  }
```

here I populate the reviews :

```
exports.getTour = factory.getOne(Tour, {path: "reviews"});


exports.getOne = (Model, popOp) => catchAsync( async(request, response, next) => {

    let query = Model.findById(request.params.id);
    // console.log(query);
    
    if(popOp) query = query.populate(popOp);
    const doc = await query;

    if(!doc) return next(new AppError(404,"No document is associated with this id"));
  
    response.status(200).json({
        status: "success",
        doc,
    });
});
```

I've read Mongoose documentation many times but couldn't figure out where is the problem in my implementation
I'm using:
"mongoose": "^7.3.4"

Comment: use a try catch block to catch and log errors. If there's an error, share the error.

Comment: @Nazrul Chowdhury no error at all, it works fine, All of the tour fields appear in Postman except the reviews